Error Decoding JSON Access Token for Daraja API When Hosting Web Service on Render
i am trying to deploy my api on render as a webservice... i have the same code in my local machine as in my git repo from which i building the service to deploy. on the deployed site hosted on render, when i send a post request to daraja api (an mpesa mobile payment natively fom kenya) i get an internal server error  with this as the message:
JSONDecodeError at /
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://rycha-pay.onrender.com/
Django Version: 5.0.6
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:    
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: /opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py, line 978, in json
Raised during:  mpesa_client.views.pay
Python Executable:  /opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.11.9
Python Path:    
['/opt/render/project/src/django_mpesa_payments',
 '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.11',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Jun 2024 10:18:40 +0000... 

on the other hand the api works perfectly fine offline and i can send requests to daraja api from my local machine and get valid response as shown in this response body...
{"MerchantRequestID": "f1e2-4b95-a71d-b30d3cdbb7a7541949", "CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_25062024132114897799004096", "ResponseCode": "0", "ResponseDescription": "Success. Request accepted for processing", "CustomerMessage": "Success. Request accepted for processing"}`....

this is the section of code that is being flagged
# Configure logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_mpesa_token():
    url = os.getenv("SAFARICOM_GET_ACCES_TOKEN_URL")
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(settings.MPESA_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.MPESA_CONSUMER_SECRET))

        # Log status code and headers
        logger.debug(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")
        logger.debug(f"Response headers: {response.headers}")

        # Log response content
        logger.debug(f"Response content: {response.text}")

        # Check if the response contains valid JSON
        try:
            token = response.json().get('access_token')
            if token:
                return token
            else:
                logger.error("Access token not found in the response.")
                raise ValueError("Access token not found in the response.")
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.error(f"JSON decoding error: {e}")
            raise

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logger.error(f"Request failed: {e}")
        raise

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        raise`

.... can anyone guide me on how to resolve this. the above issue is part of a bigger challenge that am facing which is implementing lipa na mpesa payment gateway . initially i could not get a callback from their daraja api endpoint when i tried exposing my local machine using ngrok the issue being it ngrok was  no longer supported. i then tried using python anywhere to host my end point thought still faced a challenge with receiving a callback response after the first  response from when my request had reached daraja api successfully to begin payment processing. i migrated to render hoping to find a more reliable way of testing my payment api that am developing. any better and workable solutions is much appreciated .
i have checked  the questions on stack but all are random and dont give a solution to my problem .Also i tried adding some logging so that i can view it but i dont have terminal access on  render. am not sure of how to debug this as the problem resides on my online platform but works correctly on my local machine....i expected that adding loging and debuging code directly to my code will help output the possible causes of the jsondecode error on the on the output log window provided with render for their free version but still its not much help

Your response.json() is raising an error because the returned response is not valid JSON.
If you can't access terminal logs, you can simply return the response text:
from rest_framework.response import Response
try:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(settings.MPESA_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.MPESA_CONSUMER_SECRET))
    try:
        token = response.json().get('access_token')
    except :
        return Response(response.text)
except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        raise`

Now, you should be able to view the returned response text and identify any issues with your request.
Also, if you have problems with ngrok, you can test Pinggy.
